# Pypy3 slow with dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, pypy

Why does the dictionary functions in pypy3 slows down, when the `TOTAL_NUM_DATA` is 10 million or greater.  When its 9 million, it seems much faster.

Consider `test.py` with:

```
import datetime
import random

start = datetime.datetime.now()

TOTAL_NUM_DATA = 10_000_000
ACTION = ['add', 'rem']
QUANTITY = [1, 5, 10, 20, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000]
RAND_SPREAD = 10_000

DATA = [{'action': random.choice(ACTION),
         'key': random.randint(0, RAND_SPREAD),
         'val': random.choice(QUANTITY)} for x in range(TOTAL_NUM_DATA)]

print("data: ", datetime.datetime.now() - start)



def test(DATA):
    d = {}

    for data in DATA:
        if data['action'] == 'add':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d:
                d[key] += data['val']
            else:
                d[key] = data['val']


start = datetime.datetime.now()
test(DATA)
print("done: ", datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

Output with pypy3:

```
data:  0:00:12.977063
done:  0:01:06.856763
```

Output with python3.8:

```
data:  0:00:30.279252
done:  0:00:02.483877
```

As you can see, python3.8 blazed through the test, taking only about 2s.  Where as pypy3 took over 1 minute.  Generating the DATA in pypy3 is always faster, no matter how much data there is.  Pypy3 seems to have slowed down on accessing the value in the dictionary, and also performing `if key in d`.

Whats weird is that, changing `TOTAL_NUM_DATA` to 9 million:

Output with pypy3:

```
data:  0:00:11.873104
done:  0:00:00.659081
```

Output with python3.8:

```
data:  0:00:27.464615
done:  0:00:02.245507
```

Can someone explain why this is happening for pypy3.  And also, how can I optimize this for pypy3 with data over 10 million.

Comment: Is your system's RAM being taken up? My initial thought is that the RAM is full and so your OS is resorting to [Paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging) via the disk.

Comment: Can not reproduce.  pypy3 is faster in both cases.

Comment: Good point.  I think it is almost full (I only have 4GB in my docker), but I would assume python3 used the same amount of resources

Comment: @RandomDavis You are correct, increasing the memory of the system fixed the issue.  Thanks!